# How do I avoid using the [UITableViewController loadView] when trying to present a UIViewController (and not a UITableViewController)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, uicontainerview

I am making an iPad app that, among other things contain a view in which to set options.
This "Options" View has two container-views, each holding a TableView with two different kinds of options in them, and switches to turn these options on or off. 
The problem is that when I try to make a button from my main ViewController that will open the options view, I get the following error:

[Screenshot of signal SIGABRT error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNIYJ.png)

with this in the output:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-c2d-Su-6Id" from storyboard "Options", but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

I don't know why the underlying function  [UITableViewController loadView] is used, as I do not expect my Options-view to be a TableView - the tables are in container views.

I am using different storyboards, and a segue to a storyboard reference to present the Options View modally. I have tried deleting both the button, the segue and the Storyboard reference, replacing them with new ones, and renaming my ViewController.swift file, and all the references to it, with no luck

I have also tried looking for other solutions here on the site, but I have had no luck, and I begin to fear it might be because of the tableViews in the containerViews...

I am quite new to learning swift and Xcode, so please keep your explanations simple to follow, and assume that I am completely incompetent :-)

Comment: When you made the scene in the storyboard for the Options screen did you drag out a regular view controller or a table view controller? More importantly, what is the identity of the options view controller? The message you are getting looks a lot like you drug out a table view controller that still has `UITableViewController` in the Class field of the identity inspector.

Comment: The error says that you have a view controller that is or subclasses `UITableViewController`, but the root view of that scene is not a `UITableView`

Comment: My Options ViewController has StoryboardID 'OptionViewWithTableViews' and no RestorationID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you probably added a Container View, which automatically places a "child" view controller onto the Storyboard, and then simply changed the Class of that child VC to `UITableViewController` --- which, as you found out, doesn't work.

To use a table view controller as the child, add your Container View, then add a normal `UITableViewController` to the Storyboard. Then, Ctrl-Drag from the Container View to the new table view controller and select `Embed` from the popup menu.